# Let $f($z$)= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_nz^n$ be the power series expansion of f about $0$. Prove that $|a_n| \le (n+1)(1+1/n)^{n} < e(n+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the unit disc D = {$z \in \mathbb{C}$ : |$z$| < 1} and $|$f($z$)$| \le 1/(1-|$z$|)$ for all $z\in D$.

Let $f($z$)= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_nz^n$ be the power series expansion of f about $0$.

Prove that $$|a_n| \le (n+1)(1+1/n)^{n} < e(n+1)$$

Comment: I've been working on this problem for a while now, but can't seem to get anywhere.  I've tried expressing 1/(1-$|$z$|$ as the geometric series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} |z|^n$ and writing $|f($z$)|= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } |a_n||z|^n$ $\le$ $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} |z|^n$

Comment: Also, I know that $$e=\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n.$$ My approach was to prove the $\le$ inequality first and then use this fact to show the last inequality

Comment: Please avoid using `$$` in titles.

Comment: k, thanks. sorry!

Comment: The second inequality is really easy, use $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n <e<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$

Comment: @matt No reason to apologize. It is just a matter of not making some questions pop "off" in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that Cauchy integral formula gives us
$$
a_n=
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(r e^{it})}{(re^{it})^{n+1}}d(r e^{it})=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(r e^{it})}{r^n e^{int}}dt
$$
hence
$$
|a_n|\leq
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{|f(r e^{it})|}{r^n |e^{int}|}dt\leq
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{r^n (1-|r e^{it}|)}=
\frac{1}{r^n (1-r)}
$$
As the consequence
$$
a_n\leq\min\limits_{r\in(0,1)}\frac{1}{r^n (1-r)}=(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$
I suggest you to fill the gaps.

Comment: sorry, i'm still not sure how you get the equality on the right hand side of $$a_n\leq\min\limits_{r\in(0,1)}\frac{1}{r^n (1-r)}=(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: use calculus to find point of minimum. Find derivative, find stationary points, substitute into the function

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

1. Cauchy's theorem can help you recover $a_n$ from $f$.
2. Use the inequality $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$
3. What is the minimum of $\frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z)}$ when $z\in (0,1)$?